# Camel REST to Controlbus

Tags: apache-camel

I am exposing a REST endpoint to control Camel Routes:

```
<get uri="/camel/route/{id}" produces="text/plain">
    <description>stop a camel route by its ID</description>
    <param name="id" type="path" description="Route ID" dataType="string"/>
    <param name="action" type="query" description="Action to take" dataType="string"/>
    <responseMessage message="OK" code="200" />
    <to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=${header.id}&amp;action=${header.action}"/>
</get>
```

But the control bus seems fail to resolve ID and Action as it log as:

```
ControlBusProducer - ControlBus task done [${header.action} route ${header.id}] with result -> void
```

How do I resolve REST path and query parameters in the  route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions such as `${header.action}` are not evaluated in `<to>` processors.  If you are using a recent version of Camel use `<toD>` instead.  If that's not available in your version, `<recipientList>` can do the job.

http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html